# can't figure out why a function parameter's value isn't passed to the function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in a codeigniter controller that calls a model function with 3 parameters. Of the 3 passed parameters, response_num comes across blank when it should be an integer value.
Hoping someone else's eyes can spot the trouble!
Thanks! (I'm still learning php and codigniter).

Here is the calling function in the controller:

```
for($i=1; $i < $possible_results_count; $i++) {
                print_r("iteration: ".$i);
                $g1 = $this->Response_model->get_possible_results_for_response($i, $this->session->userdata("assess_id"), $this->session->userdata("user_id"));
                print_r("Sum for ".$i."=".$g1["response_value"]);
                if($g1["response_value"] >= $sensitivity) {
                   $results[$i] = $userdata["possible_results"][$i]; // 
                    $result_count++;
                    // print_r("added [".$userdata["results"][$i]."]");
                }

                $total_results = $result_count;
                
                if ($total_results >= $min_result_count) {
                    // print_r("found 3 gifts-breaking for loop");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The called function in the model:

```
public function get_possible_results_for_response($*response_num*=FALSE, $assess_id, $registrant_id){
        print_r("response_num=".$response_num.";  assess_id=".$assess_id.";  registrant_id=".$registrant_id);
```

$i is the variable in the calling functions for loop.
the print_r's show all variables are correct except for the parameter that was passed as $i, it is blank.
$i tracks the iteration count and passes it to the model for a db lookup using $i to determine which record to use in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!
duh!!!  Right after I posted this question, I decided to initialize $i ($i=0) just before the for loop and it worked, the value was passed to the calling function. Apparently using $i in the for loop without initializing works for the for loop, but not as a regular variable unless it is initialized.

Live and Learn :)

Comment: This shouldn't have any effect at all, initializing it in the for loop itself is the most common way of setting a start value and works normally.

Comment: I second Nigel's remark. You can see for yourself [here](https://3v4l.org/2k5Mm). And that link will also introduce you to a good practice of placing optional parameters after the required ones.

Comment: Wow... I went to El_Vana's link for php eval editor I can see many issues there. Nigel, that's what I thought, although I am new to php, Why would that one addition change the behavior? Also, I commented it out and another run failed at $i.   Weird.